# How to unroot a GSM Galaxy Nexus without reverting to the stock ROM

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, unrooting, gsm

I recently rooted and unlocked the Bootloader on my Galaxy Nexus — direct from Google — using [this](http://andr0idtech.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-root-galaxy-nexus-jelly-bean-ice.html) method. Upon doing so my phone reverted to the stock Jelly Bean ROM I had just after upgrading. All of my apps and settings were removed. I've downloaded and setup all my apps again, and I want to unroot my phone in order to properly use Google Wallet.

Will unrooting my phone with the Galaxy Nexus Toolkit wipe my phone and restore the stock Jelly Bean ROM?

Comment: Does Google Wallet only work on unrooted devices?

Comment: I believe so. I haven't tried using it yet, but I can add cards and update account info. There's a notification at the top of the screen which tells me my device is unsupported (due to root access).

Comment: Interesting and funny! Because for years people come here and ask to root there phone, and now you ask how to *unroot* your phone. :-) I think you are the first one here. There should be a badge for that. But I get the point: It will increase security slightly. Although I also believe that Google Wallet may work, but who knows they could change this anytime.

Comment: Apparently Google Wallet will work fine with a rooted device, Google just displays the notification for security reasons. I have yet to test this — since I don't know of any locations in my area that accept Google Wallet.